# Vue forcing closing tags

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a dynamic form from few 100 lines of json. Each json object has a type which maps to a input/date/heading etc:

```
{ name: "input1", label: "input1 ", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "input2", label: "input2", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "title", label: "Title", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "title"},
{ name: "input3", label: "input3", placeholder: "Enter date", value: "", type: "date"},
{ name: "input4", label: "input4", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},


<template v-for="item in data">

    <template v-if="item.type === 'text'">
      <label>{{item.label}}</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
    </template>

    <template v-if="item.type === 'date'">
      <label>{{item.label}}</label>
      <input type="date" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
    </template>

    <template v-if="item.type === 'title'">
      <h1>{{item.label}}</h1>
    </template>

</template>
```

I want to group sections together in div for styling. So I tried:

```
{ name: "input1", label: "input1 ", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "input2", label: "input2", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "openDiv", label: "", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "openDiv"},
{ name: "title", label: "Title", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "title"},
{ name: "input3", label: "input3", placeholder: "Enter date", value: "", type: "date"},
{ name: "input4", label: "input4", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "closeDiv", label: "", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "closediv"},

<template v-for="item in data">

    <template v-if="item.type === 'text'">
      <label>{{item.label}}</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
    </template>

    <template v-if="item.type === 'date'">
      <label>{{item.label}}</label>
      <input type="date" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
    </template>

    <template v-if="item.type === 'title'">
      <h1>{{item.label}}</h1>
    </template>

    <template v-if="item.type === 'openDiv'">
      <div class="mydiv">
    </template>

    <template v-if="item.type === 'closediv'">
      </div>
    </template>

</template>
```

Vue is not compiling as my Div is missing a closing tag. How can I go about this? I tried v-html but this is also forcing close tags.

Comment: Vue cannot handle invalid html (because it works with the DOM tree instead of raw html), you need to find a method that gives valid html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is converting your data to a computed property, and inside that computed property, make basicly an array inside another array. Then inside your template loop over the outer array, and then conditionally loop over the first array.

While this sounds confusing, it isn't really.

1. Inside our component, we make a new computed section
2. Inside this computed section, we add a new method, lets call it "formattedData"
3. Inside this section, we need to create a variable for storing our results.
4. Since we need to know if we are inside a div block or not, we need an additional variable to keep track of this.
5. Then we loop over all incoming data,
6. if we see a `type: "closediv"`, then we replace out temporary variable with a new one, indicating an open block context
7. if we see a `type: "opendiv"`, then we replace out temporary variable with a new one, indicating an open block context
8. If something else, and our tmp array has an size of 0, it means it needs to be added to the resulting array.
9. After looping, we return our results.
10. We now transformed our data to its final form, and are ready to display it. Inside our `<template>` section, we add the first loop
11. Inside this loop, there is an if statement, that either ads the `<div>` or not
12. then we start the next loop, this loop prints out the item itself.

Example of the above logic: (used a "script-template" instead of the real `<template>` tag because the StackOverflow Snippet logic

```js
// bootstrap the demo
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  template: '#example',
  data: {
    information: [
{ name: "input1", label: "input1 ", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "input2", label: "input2", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "openDiv", label: "", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "openDiv"},
{ name: "title", label: "Title", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "title"},
{ name: "input3", label: "input3", placeholder: "Enter date", value: "", type: "date"},
{ name: "input4", label: "input4", placeholder: "Enter text", value: "", type: "text"},
{ name: "closeDiv", label: "", placeholder: "", value: "", type: "closediv"},
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    formattedData() {
      const results = [];
      let tmpObject = {
        wrapped: false,
        values: [],
      };
      for(let i = 0; i < this.information.length; i++) {
        if(this.information[i].type === 'openDiv') {
          tmpObject = {
            wrapped: true,
            values: [],
          };
          continue;
        }
        if(this.information[i].type === 'closediv') {
          // TODO Is the capitalization of `closediv` intentional?
          tmpObject = {
            wrapped: false,
            values: [],
          };
          continue;
        }
        if(tmpObject.values.length === 0) {
          results.push(tmpObject);
        }
        tmpObject.values.push(this.information[i]);
      }
      return results;
    }
  },
  methods: {},
});
```

```css
div.testDiv {
border: red solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="example">
  <div>
    <template v-for="data in formattedData">

      <div v-if="data.wrapped" class="testDiv">
        <template v-for="item in data.values">
          <template v-if="item.type === 'text'">
            <label>{{item.label}}</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
          </template>

          <template v-if="item.type === 'date'">
            <label>{{item.label}}</label>
            <input type="date" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
          </template>

          <template v-if="item.type === 'title'">
            <h1>{{item.label}}</h1>
          </template>
        </template>
      </div>
      <template v-else>
        <template v-for="item in data.values">
          <template v-if="item.type === 'text'">
            <label>{{item.label}}</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
          </template>

          <template v-if="item.type === 'date'">
            <label>{{item.label}}</label>
            <input type="date" v-model="item.value" :placeholder="item.placeholder" />
          </template>

          <template v-if="item.type === 'title'">
            <h1>{{item.label}}</h1>
          </template>
        </template>
      </template>
    </template>
    <hr>
    <pre>{{ this.formattedData }}</pre>
  </div>
</script>



<div id="demo"></div>
```